# operator '+=' cannot be applied to types 'object' and 'EventHandler'

Tags: c#, wpf

Why does the following code throw this error?

> "operator '+=' cannot be applied to types 'object' and
>   'EventHandler'".

```
ComboBox cmbx = new ComboBox();
cmbx.SelectedItem += new EventHandler(cmbx_SelectedItem);

void cmbx_SelectedItem(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cmbbx = sender as ComboBox;
}
```

Comment: `SelectedItem` isn't an event, you can't subscribe event handler to it

Comment: `SelectedItem` is a property, not an event that you can subscribe to. Perhaps you want to handle `SelectedIndexChanged`?

Answer (score 12):

[`SelectedItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx) isn't an event, it's a property.

You probably want to listen to either [`SelectedIndexChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`SelectedValueChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx).